# list of modified projects in svn

Tags: svn

I have a requirement to list the modified project names from svn. 
Svn update gives the list of files modified, where as what I'm looking for is a list of modified projects (modules)

U ProjectA/src/module1/xxx1.xx

U ProjectA/src/module1/xxx2.xx

U ProjectB/src/module1/xxxx.xx

U ProjectC/src/module1/xxxx.xx

I would like to have the list as ProjectA, ProjectB, ProjectC. Is there a way I can achive this.
Please help.

Comment: * list when?
* modified when?
* have it to be client-side or repository-side checker?

Comment: You'd have to do some parsing of the modified file paths, assuming each modified file belongs to one and only one project/module

Comment: I have job configured in hudson, which reads pools the svn changes and my build script runs per project ( I can't modify this). I would like to have the hudsdon change log parsed and read projects updated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on a Linux/Mac? If yes, try the following

```
svn st | grep "^M" | sed 's/U \+\([^\/]\+\).*/\1/g' | uniq
```